# If AC is constantly changing direction, how does it ever move?

Tags: ac

I know this is probably really basic, but it's very confusing to me.

Comment: what do you mean by 'move'?

Comment: When most people walk their legs are constantly changing direction so... **<fill this bit in yourself>**.

Comment: Move? Who? *<ready to catch the moving wall outlet>*

Comment: You are thinking of it wrong. It is not your fault. Wires are sort of like a hose, except they are full of electrons rather than water. Electrons go in one side, and this pushes on the electrons in the wire so that whenever one goes in, one must go out the other side (because the wire is full). In AC, the electrons move back and forth, but that is still a current, and it can be used to do work.

Comment: it's's like waves that move in the ocean but the water just moves back and forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think about it as a transfer of energy it may make more sense. Andy's comment is right on. You move your legs back and forth and still get motion. Another example might be an internal combustion engine. A piston moves both up and down, yet that is translated into a rotation only in one direction.
For AC, the act of the current first moving in one direction can impart electrical energy into a circuit, then, when it moves in the other direction, it once again imparts energy into that circuit, only with the opposite voltage. 
An incandescent light bulb runs on AC. When the current is flowing in one direction, the filament in the bulb is heated and produces light. The same thing happens when the current then flows in the other direction. The filament doesn't care which way current flows through it. Some circuits require DC current, and there are rectifying circuits that turn AC into DC. In fact, if you look at some circuits that explain how an AC to DC converter works, it may help further your understanding of AC.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

When you speak, air molecules just vibrate back and forth in position. Yet the sound of your voice reaches much further than any individual molecule moves.

The individual charge-carrying particles don't move, on average. But the in-place vibration of one causes a similar *pattern of motion* to be translated down the conductor. Each one transfers energy to its neighbor.

[image]